# Summing up values for specific names for a specific period?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

My goal is to sum up values in a column for specific names and a specific period of time. I've got a column of names [name]), a column of integer values that I wanna sum up ([Values]) and another column of integer values ([Day]). I want to sum up the values grouped by name for each day.

So for example if there is a name "Chris" with value 4 on day 1 and there is another entry "Chris" with value 2 on day 3, I want to show the sum of chris on day_1 (4) and on day_2 (4+2=6).

I have already got some working code (see below) BUT: this code only sums up every value from day 1 until day X. I am not able to find a code that is able to sum up values for a specific period of time. Lets say there is an entry "Ralph" at Day 27.

My original code sums up every value for Ralph until day 27 but now i want to sum up values for a specific time range, I wanna sum up every value for each name in the column from the last 20 days for example. How is this possible?

```
select name, day, value, name2, value2,
sum(value) over (partition by name order by day) SumValue,
sum(value2) over (partition by name2 order by day) SumValue2
from (select *, row_number() over (order by day) rn from tablename) as t
order by rn
```

NOTE: The sequence of the rows needs to stay the same.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `where day = 27` or `where day between 12 and 15` before the `order by` do it?

Comment: Sample data and desired resultswould really help.

Comment: Your completely right @OlivierJacot-Descombes! Can be that easy! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below script-

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Name,Day,SUM(Value) S_Val
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY Name,Day
)

SELECT A.Name,A.Day,
(
    SELECT SUM(B.S_Val) 
    FROM CTE B 
    WHERE B.Name = A.Name 
    AND B.Day <= A.Day
) AS Running_Sum
FROM CTE A
ORDER BY A.Name,A.Day
```